# Rails Autocomplete Using Instance Method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-autocomplete

I am running Rails 4, using the `rails-jquery-autocomplete` gem - I have everything hooked up so it works fine to autocomplete models where there is a `:name` column.

What I'm struggling with is how to autocomplete a `name` where it is an instance method. I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Roster < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :practice
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :compensation_type

  def name
    self.practice.name + ' - ' + self.role.role_type.name + ' (' + self.role.name + ') - ' + self.compensation_type.name
  end
end
```

This should make it fairly easy to see what I'm trying to do - autocomplete on the name method.

The method itself works:

```
2.2.2 :002 > roster1.name
  Practice Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "practices".* FROM "practices" WHERE "practices"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Role Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  RoleType Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "role_types".* FROM "role_types" WHERE "role_types"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CompensationType Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "compensation_types".* FROM "compensation_types" WHERE "compensation_types"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => "Test Practice - Role Name Test (Role Type Test) - Test Comp Type"
```

So the problem seems to be the autocomplete. The form loads, and I can see in the console that the following error is thrown:

```
Started GET "/bookings/autocomplete_roster_name?term=Te" for ::1 at 2015-08-22 09:18:32 +0100
Processing by BookingsController#autocomplete_roster_name as JSON
  Parameters: {"term"=>"Te"}
  Roster Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  rosters.id, rosters.name FROM "rosters" WHERE (LOWER(rosters.name) LIKE 'ar%')  ORDER BY LOWER(rosters.name) ASC LIMIT 10
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: rosters.name: SELECT  rosters.id, rosters.name FROM "rosters" WHERE (LOWER(rosters.name) LIKE 'Te%')  ORDER BY LOWER(rosters.name) ASC LIMIT 10
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

The first obvious thing is that the SQL is totally different - it isn't trying to pull together the three pieces of info and combine them, it's just looking for a `:name` column.

Is there a way to make this work with a custom instance method instead of an actual column? Can I make my instance method behave like a column?

For completeness, my controller for the form:

```
autocomplete :roster, :name
```

and on my form I have:

```
<%= f.input :roster, as: :autocomplete, url: autocomplete_roster_name_bookings_path, id_element: '#booking_roster_id', input_html: { class: 'form-control' }  %>
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize [`autocomple`](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete#sending-extra-search-fields) action:

```
def autocomplete_roster_name 
  # your code here
  result = Model.where('custome query here')
  render json: result.to_json
end
```

But you should make a select query and concat it on the database layer.